# URL rewrite in IIS6 - Third party tools

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have collected the following api/sdk/whatever which provide modules for doing url rewriting in IIS 5/6/7. Some are free-open source and some require $.

I haven't tried any of them. I would like to know if anyone is currently using or used or have any kind of experience with these tools (website listed).

```
UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewrite - http://www.urlrewriting.net/159/en/downloads.html

IIS Mod-Rewrite Pro ($) -http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1469

Open Source - http://urlrewriter.net/

Helicon Tech (Full $)- http://www.isapirewrite.com/

ISAPI_ Rewrite 3.0 ($) - http://www.seoconsultants.com/windows/isapi/3/

Open Source Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter - http://iirf.codeplex.com/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Murali

Answer (score 1):

I have personal experience with IIRF from the codeplex site, and I liked it and found it good.

Answer (score 0):

I use UrlRewrite from UrlRewriting.Net

Very easy to use for the simple thing I'm doing: send .pdf requests to an aspx page to generate the pdf.

Comment: What i am trying to do:
http://myweb.com/this_is_url_rewrite should point to
http://myweb.com?default.aspx?q=this_is_url_rewrite

Is this possible using UrlRewriting.Net?

Thanks

Comment: yes it is. Their documentation is useful - http://www.urlrewriting.net/160/en/documentation.html. You just have to put the rewrite rules and reference the assembly in the web.config and you're good to go.

Comment: Excellent! will that a shot. I have been now playing with IIRF and i kinda like it too.